# Using Amazon cloud - do I need a NA location?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud

If I have my files hosted on Amazon S3, why would I need to use a cloud for North America?  Wouldn't it just download from S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 has multiple regions. Currently [there are four](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#pricing). Each S3 bucket is in a specific region. If you're using EC2 you will get the lowest prices (free bandwidth) and best performance (latency and bandwidth) if you use an S3 bucket in the same region as your EC2 instance.

Comment: I thought you could just use 1 S3 bucket in a single region and use all the cloud services with all of them?

Comment: Yes, you can create a single S3 bucket and access it via http://yourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com from any location, inside or outside of EC2. You will pay more bandwidth fees and your performance will be worse if you use a S3 bucket from another region. It will still work.